# attempting to reference a deleted function using string

Tags: c++

I have union:

```
union dataUnion
{

    struct data1
    {
        string textString;                   
    }dataStruct1;

    struct data2
    {
        unsigned char dataChar;
    }dataStruct2;
};
```

Now I created class:

```
class testC
{
public:
    union dataUnion data;
};

testC classDataC;
```

I got error: attempting to reference a deleted function
When I change string textString to unsigned char textString it work ok. 
Is it possible that string will work well?

Comment: You cannot put classes w/constructors and/or destructors into a union.

Comment: An `unsigned char` is _not_ a string, or anything like a string. It's just one byte. One number.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition That doesn't mean you could never want to union it with a string though.

Comment: @MrLister: Of course, but that's not what the OP is doing with _"when I change string textString to unsigned char"_.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Oh, I assumed that was just a test to see if including a string there was indeed the problem. Not a possible workaround to the problem!

Comment: @MrLister: It could be

Answer (score 0):

You need to read again the chapter in your book about unions, because [they can't do this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union); if the destructor or copy/move constructors/operators are non-trivial, *it cannot be a union member*. Think about what would otherwise happen when your union goes out of scope. Which destructor gets called?

A nice alternative is a tagged union, a more complex but more robust type that uses placement-new to finely control object lifetime. This allows for the use of complex types, such as `std::string`, as members. A good implementation is `boost::variant`.